# Why do my iOS apps (.ipa) show up in my 'Open With" context menu in Finder?

Tags: osx-lion

Why do my iOS mobile apps that I build show up in the "open with" context menu in Finder?  And How can I remove them?

I am currently running the latest version of OSX-Lion but don't understand why the OS thinks my mobile apps are OSX app.

Comment: For which documents? All?

Comment: Yes for all documents.  The mobile apps I develop allow document interaction on iOS so I think that's a reason why they show up...

However, I dont understand why they are showing up in the "Open With" context menu in Finder... They're built for iOS, not my Mac

Answer (score 0):

Well, I still don't know why my iOS apps [archives] are being considered as actual apps that can be run as a desktop app, but I've figured out how to "clear out" the apps that are shown in the OpenWith context menu.

For Lion, execute the following to reset your LaunchServices database and it'll clear it out.

/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Support/lsregister -kill -r -domain local -domain system -domain user

The downside is that I have to reset and clear things out every once and awhile so the above is not a solution, just a workaround for now.